# Regex.Replace not replacing the whole string instead replacing chars in string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, replace

My code is as follow:

```
ArticleContent = Regex.Replace(_article.Article, "[QUOTE]", "<p class='quote'><span style='font-size:1.8em !important;'>" + _article.NewFields.Quotes + "</span></p>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The problem i'm facing here is, the Regex is not replacing the whole occurrence of the string '[QUOTE]'. Instead it is searching for the letters q,u,o,t,e and replacing them with the replace string. I know the issue is because of the square brackets, but i want that to be replaced as well. Please help.

Comment: `@"\[QUOTE\]"` what else you need?

Answer (score 0):

Use an non capturing group to replace all the occurrences of the string `QUOTE` with your desired string ,

```
(?:QUOTE)
```

So your code should be,

```
ArticleContent = Regex.Replace(_article.Article, "(?:QUOTE)", "<p class='quote'><span style='font-size:1.8em !important;'>" + _article.NewFields.Quotes + "</span></p>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

OR

Try to escape the square brackets, if you want to replace `[QUOTE]` with some-other string becuase suare brackets in regex have a special meaning.

```
\[QUOTE\]
```

And your code should be,

```
ArticleContent = Regex.Replace(_article.Article, "\[QUOTE\]", "<p class='quote'><span style='font-size:1.8em !important;'>" + _article.NewFields.Quotes + "</span></p>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: will this replace the square brackets, because the brackets are a part of my string

Comment: @FarhanMukadam Why don't you just try it and find out?

Comment: @tnw  the above code is not ignoring the case of the string 'QUOTE'.

Answer (score 0):

You must escape square brackets! And don't forget REGEXP are case sensitive. Here's my correction to your code:

```
ArticleContent = Regex.Replace(_article.Article, "\[quote\]", "<p class='quote'><span style='font-size:1.8em !important;'>" + _article.NewFields.Quotes + "</span></p>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

By the way, I don't see any accourrence of 'quote' enclosed in brackets, so I'm not sure I got what you're trying to do...

Comment: _article.Article returns me an html formal content of my article, in that i'm trying to replace 'quote'